# "This password reset token is invalid" after setting locale prefix on laravel 6.9.0

Tags: php, laravel

i am having this issue when trying to reset a password, after setting the locale in my routes/web like this:

**ROUTES/WEB**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});

Route::group( [ 'prefix' => '{locale}', 'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'], 'middleware' => 'locale' ], function () {

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    })->name('welcome');

    // Auth::routes(['reset' => false]);
    Auth::routes(['except' => 'reset']);

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

    // register
    Route::post('register/', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm')->name('registerplan');
    Route::post('register/create', 'Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('register');
});
```

As you can see, i have a prefix that i have to set on all links, and i have a *middleware* **locale** where i set the locale prefix as a default to void setting the locale in each link every time

**LOCALE MIDDLEWARE**

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class Locale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->segment(1));
        URL::defaults(['locale' => $request->segment(1)]);
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

So far so good, now the problem comes when i try to reset an user password; after clicking on the reset link (**example:** https://cubik.app//en/password/reset/72216cd4f35fce0bf2aee9c2e09ffe16cae3a26175c752cb987df59e0312d60d?email=example%40demo.com) on the email send from the laravel app, and filling up the reset password form, getting the error **This password reset token is invalid.**

**WHAT I TRY**

I test moving the **auth routes** outside of the prefix group in the *routes/web* file and the reset works, so ...

**MY CONCLUTION**

Probably the *ForgotPasswordController* is getting the **locale** instead of the **token** but i dont know how to fix it.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\SendsPasswordResetEmails;

class ForgotPasswordController extends Controller
{
    use SendsPasswordResetEmails;
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help dev family!

Comment: When you generate a reset link, after your app name and before the locale there are two `//` that makes the token invalid.

Comment: I just fix that in the URL but that dont fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

I went with a similar approach for a multilingual project.

The problem is that the token is now being set by your `{locale}` prefix, which causes the invalid token issue.

To fix it you will need to override the `showResetForm()` function from `/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php` in your `/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php` controller to:

```php
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    $token = $request->token;

    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

This should fix the invalid token issue when trying to reset a user's password.

Comment: can u please explain a bit

Comment: In this scenario, when using a prefix, `$token` would have the prefix as its value because it is no long the first parameter. Thus, not matching the created token which is stored in the database.

By overriding the `showResetForm()` function and setting `$token = $request->token;` we are getting the correct parameter and its value, and again matching the token stored in de database.

Answer (score 0):

```
##ResetPassword.php  ###Chnanged URL {locale}##   
$locale=app()->getLocale();   
return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
            ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
           // ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
           ->action('Reset Password', url($locale . '/password/reset', $this->token))

            ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
            ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
    }



##############ResetPasswordController  ##
##Add this code in ResetPasswordController ##

    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    $token = $request->token;

    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```